# Methods to enable Sql Notification Services

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, caching, notifications, sqldependency

What is the difference in the following mentioned things, are these used for differnet purposes or are they used collectively for some functionality, can anyone please differentiante among these based on their functionalities:

```
   1) SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(ConnStr)
   2) AspNet_RegSql.exe -S "ServerName" -d "DatabaseName" -ed
   3) set enable_broker
   4) SqlDependency.Start(connStr)
```